# Automatic Table of Contents showing all the same page number

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents, page-numbers

I've created an automatic table of contents within Microsoft Word. It has successfully populated the headings with the correct information; however, all of the page numbers show 1 the whole way down.

I've inserted page numbers into the header and then updated the table of contents; however, the page numbering problem hasn't changed.

Comment: What happens if you select the TOC and press F9?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that I have to force the page numbers on some of my documents to get it to work with TOC.  If you edit the header section of the document, it should bring up a "design" tab in the ribbon.  Select the Page Number button on the left and click on format page number.  Then change the page numbering to Start at.  Then put the page number that it should be, and exit the header edit mode and it should update correctly in TOC.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today and after some trials I deleted my headers completely, copy-pasted the headers from our template, and inserted "Page Numbers" at the top of my page from the "Header and Footer Tools" tab. This solved the "same page number problem" for me.

My main problem after this was that I didn't wanted the first and second pages to have the headers. I've found out that inserting "Section breaks" instead of "Page breaks" at page endings did help out to split the document into different sections. This way you still keep a TOC and page numbers which track the whole document but can break the headers into different rule zones.

[image: Header and Footer Tools]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behavior, except my page numbers were all 2.
I found a work-around on some other blog posts that suggested using "Lock Tracking" in combination with "No Markup", and that did help as a work-around.
But then I noticed some of my other documents did not have the same problem, so after further research I realized that the document with trouble was using Shapes with formatted text as the section headers. I was doing this to provide a style bar with a solid color behand the section title.  When I removed the text from the shape, and followed a different strategy of using plain/formatted text for section headers, and placing a shape (with no text) behind for my style, then the problem went away altogether.

Answer (score -1):

The author had put "start on p. 1" or "start on p. 39" or other specific page numbers in the page number format. Too bad I didn't pay attention to it before i put in all the section breaks. Now I have to go in and change page numbering to Continue from previous section in each section I created. But that is fixing the problem. Altho some pre-existing sections for tables and image are causing pagination problems too.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question. Can you clearify?